# Does a React Context update on history.push('/')

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm using a React Context `const Context = React.createContext()` with a `useEffect` hook to set a variable in my outer-most component that wraps my entire app. On a child component within my app I am using `history.push('/')` to route back to the root. This does **not** appear to trigger an update on my Context variable. Is this expected? If so, is there a better way to route that would update my context variable?

I'm using `react 16.14.0` & `react-router-dom 5.2.0`.

For example, in the code below. Shouldnt `var` increment on `history.push('/')`

**Context.js**

```
const Context= React.createContext();

const ContextProvider= (props) => {
  const [var, setVar] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setVar(var++)
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={user}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
...
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
...

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  function doSomething(){
    history.push('/')
  }
}
return(
    <Button onClick={() => doSomething()} />
)
```

Comment: Share some sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This does not appear to trigger an update on my Context variable. Is this expected?

Changing the history does not cause context providers to rerender. You mention you have a useEffect, and in principle you could write some code in that useEffect which would listen to the history, and when it gets a change it sets state to cause a rerender. If you have code in there that you think is supposed to listen for history changes, feel free to share that and i'll comment on it.

However, instead of writing your own code to listen for changes, i'd recommend using the [hooks provided by react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory). The `useHistory` and `useLocation` hooks will both listen for changes and rerender the component.

```
const Example = () => {
  // When the location changes, Example will rerender
  const location = useLocation();
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('foo');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (/* check something you care about in the location */) {
      setSomeState('bar');
    }
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={someState}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated question with some example code. You have answered my question but but feel free to leave suggestions based on my updated code example.