# I want to navigate to a page/component where I passed the data from another component using both React hooks and useHistory, but I get undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to react 3 weeks so far.
After login into my dummy app, I fetch users from the database (useEffect) as a button. I want to click on a specific user and access his/her data on the next page. Therefore, I use the context API and the useHistory to respectively send the data (state) of the selected user to the component and usehistory to navigate to that component. However, when route to that component, I receive UNDEFINED for the data I made accessible to the component.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { useToken } from '../auth/useToken';
    import { useUser } from '../auth/useUser';
    import { ClassDetails } from './ClassPages/ClassDetails';

    export const classSelectedContext = React.createContext();
    
    export const ClassSelection = () => {
    
        const user = useUser();
        const [token, setToken] = useToken();
        const [classesList, setClassesList] = useState([]);
        const [selectedClass, setSelectedClass] = useState('');
        const [className, setClassName] = useState('');
        const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
        const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');
    
        const history = useHistory();
        
        const authStr = 'Bearer '.concat(token); 
    
        useEffect( () =>{
            axios.get('http://localhost:8081/user/instructor-classes',  {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': authStr
                }
            })
            .then (res => {
                setClassesList(res.data);
            })
            .catch(
                err =>{
                    console.log(err);
                    history.push("/")
                }
            );
        
        },[selectedClass]);
        
        const AddNewClassClicked = () => {
            axios.post('http://localhost:8081/user/class', {
                className: className,
                startDate: startDate,
                endDate: endDate,
            }, {
                headers : {
                    'Authorization': authStr,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            } )
            .then(
                //window.location.reload()
            )
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
       }
    
            const onSelectedClassClicked = () =>{
                  {history.push('class-detail')} 
            }
    
    
        return (
            <div className="content-container">
                <div className="content-container">
    
                    <h1>Your current classes</h1>
                        {classesList.map(item => (
                        <button 
                            value={item.classIdentifier}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                setSelectedClass(e.target.value)
                                onSelectedClassClicked()
                            }}>
                            {item.className}
                        </button>
                        
                        )) } 
                    <classSelectedContext.Provider value={selectedClass} >
                        <ClassDetails />
                    </classSelectedContext.Provider>
                    
                </div>
    
                <div className="content-container">
                    <h1>Add a new Class</h1>
                    <input
                        value={className}
                        onChange={e => setClassName(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Class Name" />
                    <input
                        value={startDate}
                        onChange={e => setStartDate(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Start Date of the Class" /> 
                    <input
                        value={endDate}
                        onChange={e => setEndDate(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="End Date of the Class" />               
                    
                    <button
                        disabled={
                            !className || !startDate ||
                            !endDate 
                        }
                    onClick={AddNewClassClicked}>add new Class</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    
    }
```

So, After the click of the button, I am using history to get to ClassDetails (class-detail) where I can get the data passed to that component through the useEffect hook.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
    import { classSelectedContext } from '../ClassSelection';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { useToken } from '../../auth/useToken';

    export const ClassDetails = () => {
        
        const [token, setToken] = useToken();
    
        const history = useHistory();
        const authStr = 'Bearer '.concat(token); 
        let context = useContext(classSelectedContext);
    
    
        useEffect( () =>{
            console.log(context)
        
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/user/class/${context}`,  {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': authStr
                }
            })
            .then (res => {  
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(
                err =>{
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("An error happenned")
                }
            );
         }, []);
       
        return (
            <div>
                welcome {context}
                <div>
                    { GetClassDetail(context) }
                </div>
                {/* <classSelectedContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        
                        variable => { GetClassDetail(variable)}
                    }
                </classSelectedContext.Consumer> */}
           </div>
        )
    }
```

At last, these are my routes

```
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { LogInPage } from './pages/LogInPage';
    import { SignUpPage } from './pages/SignUpPage';
    import { UserInfoPage } from './pages/UserInfoPage';
    import { PrivateRoute } from './auth/PrivateRoute';
    import { ClassSelection } from './pages/ClassSelection';
    import { WelcomePage } from './pages/WelcomePage';
    import { UserLogIn } from './pages/UserLogIn';
    import { ClassDetails } from './pages/ClassPages/ClassDetails';

    export const Routes = () => {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/class-detail" exact>
                        <ClassDetails />
                    </PrivateRoute> 
                    <PrivateRoute path="/instructor-classes" exact>
                        <ClassSelection />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/select-school" exact>
                        <UserInfoPage />
                    </PrivateRoute>
                    <Route path="/user-login">
                        <UserLogIn />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/teacher-login">
                        <LogInPage />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <WelcomePage />
                    </Route>                
                    <Route path="/signup">
                        <SignUpPage />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code [in this codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-with-route-lpz20). I have tried to create a small application you are trying to make. I have added a wrapper of context to the router so that it will be available with route change. you can use render prop also and add provider with individual component like the below code.

`<Route path="/" render={(props) => (<ContextB><Component2 {...props}/></ContextB>)}/>`

Also history will work only if the component is wrapped inside
"react router dom" in your code may be you are handling.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome. I needed to pass more than 1 parameter to the useHistory hook and use the uselocation to get the parameter as such:

```
  history.push({
            pathname: "/class-detail",
            search: "?id=someId",
            hash: "#someHash",
            state: { someState}
          })
```

then I can use useLocation hook the following way in the component you wish to use the state:

```
let context = useLocation(history.state);
console.log(context) //this will give you a Json of the history you pushed.
```

Answer (score 1):

One thought -- you don't include an async/await on your button click for the axios call. Might the onSelectedClassClicked run, pushing you to the class details component before the axios call returns any data, thus your classDetails will remain undefined?

Also it looks like you're missing a set of braces around the AddNewClassClicked block, it looked like onSelectedClassClicked was within that function.

Comment: I fixed the bracket issue, but await/ async is sort of synonymous with Promise/then/catch. Isn't?

Comment: this is pushing the edge of my knowledge, but if I have to guess -- yes, it's synonymous, but in your button onClick function you need to indicate that you are awaiting a promise that the useeffect function is returning. the then/catch is used to await for the axios function to return. Maybe something like:

```
<button 
       value={item.classIdentifier}
       onClick={async (e) => {
           await setSelectedClass(e.target.value)
           onSelectedClassClicked()
        }}>
        {item.className}
</button>
```

Comment: I think it comes down to the following question: Does the context API work when useHistory hook is used to change components?

Comment: Looks like maybe try useLocation instead of useHistory in order to trigger a rerender? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66875410/does-a-react-context-update-on-history-push